# How to make floats inside container but without wrapping

Tags: html, css

I have

```
        <div id="cont">
    <div>a</div>
    <div>b</div>
    <div>c</div>
    <div>d</div>
    </div>

#cont div
{
   float: left
}
```

What happens is:

```
a b 
c d
```

I want to make them:

```
a b c d
```

which means - I dont mind them not to wrap... and not to have a scroll!

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are only two ways to get around the browsers' natural behavior of wrapping the floats.

1: Assign a width to the #cont element.

2: Use tables instead.

Comment: I did table. it looks better. but the table is widened when the content is long!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a fixed width to your container div.
If you don't want a scrollbar to be appear, then you can use `overflow: hidden` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Play with the display: inline property with some of your `<div>`s.

Normally, a `<div>` is displayed as a block, which means what follows will appear below. Setting it to inline makes it flow with the text.

Answer (score 0):

This CSS should do it :

```
#cont div
{
    display:inline;
}

#cont
{
    overflow-x:scroll; /*Not sure if you want a scroll or not. Use overflow-x:hidden; if you don't want it.*/
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:hidden` and set `width` to your div

```
#cont { width:500px; overflow:hidden; }
#cont div { width:125px; float:left; }
```